# Login Levels using JDBC in android studio

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I am busy with creating a login page which connects to a database to check the credentials. Now i am trying to create a line of code to say that if you are employee position 1 you go to Main2Activity and if you are employee position 2 you go to Main3Activity.

Here is my code:

```
String query = "select * from cc_employee where employee_username= '" + usernam.toString() + "' and employee_password = '"+ passwordd.toString() +"'  ";
                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                        if(rs.next())
                        {
                            z = "Login successful";
                            type = rs.getString("employee_position");
                            isSuccess=true;
                            con.close();
                            if (type = "1"){
                                Intent i=new Intent(login.this,Main2Activity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                            else {
                                Intent i=new Intent(login.this,Main3Activity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            z = "Invalid Credentials!";
                            isSuccess = false;
                        }
```

And Here is the image of my database[image: Database]

Comment: This code is rife with problems.  First, it looks like you are comparing and storing the raw cleartext password.  Don't do that, store a hashed version of the password.  Also, `if (type = "1")` makes an assignment to `type`, it doesn't check the value of `type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer which worked for me

```
String query = "select * from cc_employee where employee_username= '" + usernam.toString() + "' and employee_password = '"+ passwordd.toString() +"'  ";                            
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        z = "Login successful";
                        type = rs.getInt("employee_position");
                        isSuccess=true;
                        con.close();

                        switch (type){
                            case 1:
                                intent = new Intent(login.this,Main2Activity.class);
                                break;
                            case 2:

                            intent = new Intent(login.this,Main3Activity.class);
                            break;

                            case 3:
                                intent = new Intent(login.this,Main4Activity.class);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                intent = new Intent(login.this,Main5Activity.class);
                                break;
                        }
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        z = "Invalid Credentials!";
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
```